# Forcing { } to indent and be on their own line

Tags: c, clang-format

For reasons beyond my control, I must use a C coding style with this handling of `{` and `}`

```
    if (lisa())
        {
        while (mary())
            {
            john();
            anna();
            }
        }
    else if (bart())
        {
        do
            {
            jack();
            }
        while (paul());
        }
```

That is

1. The left of a normal code in a block is aligned to it's opening and closing `{` and `}` (I do not find this in any of the standard styles).
2. `{` and `}` delimiting a code block are the single non-whitespace characters on a line (perhaps, excluding comments)
3. (If supported): Even when C makes them optional, explicit `{` and `}` are enforced after `for (…)`, `do`, `while (…)` when not matching an earlier `do`, `if (…)`, and `else` except when immediately followed by `if`.

What widely supported attributes should I add/change in my minimal `.clang-format` file to get this behavior?

```
---
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
ColumnLimit: '120'
TabWidth: '4'
UseTab: Never

...
```

Comment: `For reasons beyond my control,` You are absolved, but I hope you complained to the person in control. Have you considered GNU indent?

Comment: I thought hanging indents stopped being considered cool some time around the end of the 90s. Whoever is responsible for enforcing this coding style should know there will be less productivity and more bugs. I actually cannot read this code without doing mental gymnastics.

Comment: `BreakBeforeBraces: Whitesmiths` is almost there, but it's doing `} while (paul());` with newline.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I tried `GNU`, and the braces are only halfway, not acceptable. But `BreakBeforeBraces: Whitesmiths` is close enough to 1 and 2, including for `} while (paul());` if I discipline myself to insert `//` and a newline before the `while`. Now if we can add some further incantation for 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried creating a custom behavior, i.e. `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` to match your needs but I'm quite confident that it is not achievable with clang-format-14 (nor with clang-format-16 based on the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) which I was continuously using like a look-up table).

If it is set to use: `BreakBeforeBraces: Whitesmiths` code looks almost identical to your needs as Kamil wrote in the comments but while in do-while is not on a new line.

If it is set to use: `BreakBeforeBraces: GNU` while appears on a new line but there are loads of other problems. e.g. code is not horizontally aligned with the braces.

It seems that the closest you can get is to use these options in `.clang-format` file:

```
Language: Cpp
BreakBeforeBraces: Whitesmiths
IndentWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```